# Trying to create a random word game that will output a function with a click of an html button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a word game that will choose a random item from a list but some of the items have different weights so they show up less often. I want the function to be called once the user presses a HTML button. I have the code working fairly well right now (to the console). My question is how can I get the output from the function into the html web page. If anyone could help me with this, it would be a huge help.

Here's my code:

```
var item = {
    'apple':10,
    'banana':10,
    'orange':10,
    'grapes':1,
}

function testGame(input) {
    var array = [];
        for(var item in input) {
            if(input.hasOwnProperty(item) ) {
                for(var i=0; i<input[item]; i++ ) {
                    array.push(item);
                }
            }
        }
        return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

console.log(testGame(item));
```

I have some HTML code too, just don't know where or how to write the button code properly to produce the outcome I'm looking for.

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Randomizer Game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Game</h1>   
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <button onclick="testGame();">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make new function where you can call it on button just like you called it with **console.log**:

```
<button onclick="start();">Test</button>
```

and call your randomizing function inside:

```
function start() {
  testGame(item)
}
```

Then inside `function testGame` don't use return, just save random word result in variable and print it in HTML:

```
  var result = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  console.clear();
  console.log(result);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=result;
```

I have added div result in HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

**EXAMPLE SNIPPET:**

```js
var item = {
  'apple': 10,
  'banana': 10,
  'orange': 10,
  'grapes': 1,
}

function testGame(input) {

  var array = [];
  for (var item in input) {
    if (input.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < input[item]; i++) {
        array.push(item);
      }
    }
  }
  var result = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  console.clear();
  console.log(result);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=result;
  
}

function start() {
  testGame(item)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Randomizer Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Game</h1>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <button onclick="start();">Test</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @briannelson95 Great, please consider to mark  answer as accepted on ✔︎ ,to mark it as solved for others. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementById` to get an element by id, for this I gave your button an id. With `addEventListener` you can add an event (here: click) to be call a function.
Doing here your randomizing. Get the element where you want the output again with `getElementById`and add with `textContent` your answer to it.

```js
const ITEMS = {
    'apple':10,
    'banana':10,
    'orange':10,
    'grapes':1,
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function testGame() {
    var array = [];
    for(var item in ITEMS) {
      if(ITEMS.hasOwnProperty(item) ) {
        for(var i=0; i<ITEMS[item]; i++ ) {
          array.push(item);
        }
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('item').textContent = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Randomizer Game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Game</h1>   
  <button id='btn'>Test</button>
  <div id='item'></div>
</body>
</html>
```